# WPF control performance

Tags: .net, wpf, performance

What is a good (and preferably simple) way to test the rendering performance of WPF custom controls?  I have several complex controls in which rendering performance is highly crucial.  I want to be able to make sure that I can have lots of them drawwing out in a designer with a minimal impact on performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tool called Perforator will help you.
See following article for details:

[Performance Profiling Tools for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx)